# STLink V2 VCP doesn't show up in Windows

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, serial-port, embedded

I'm trying to get myself situated to program comfortably with my STM32 Blue Pill and STLink V2 USB interface. However, I've run into an issue when trying to gain access to the VCP (*Virtual COM Port*) that the STLink is supposed to open up for me when I plug it into my computer. I've installed the latest drivers from the ST website.

I upload the USB bootloader to the STM32 and then upload a program over the STLink.

After this, I no longer have access to a serial port over the USB connection to the blue pill or STLink (*which never worked previously, and is what I'm trying to get working*).

In accordance with [multiple sources I've found](https://www.carminenoviello.com/2015/03/02/how-to-use-stm32-nucleo-serial-port/) online, I expect to see a COM port for serial communication, but I don't. All I see in Device Manager is the STLink programmer.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this situation and properly configure the STLink to show its COM port?

Answer (score 0):

The driver is normally being installed when you install a official supportd IDE like STM32CubeIDE, keil oder IAR.

You can also install it by using this:
https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link009.html

The virtual port should show up then!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1122816)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the driver, if not resolved with this trick,
Uninstalled STM32CubeIDE from the system, Reinstalling it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).